# How does one pull a specific number from an array of randomly generated numbers using an if...else statement?

Tags: c++

```
bool StatsArray::isNumberFound(int someNumber)
{

    if (data[SIZE] == someNumber)
        {
            cout << "Congrats, you have a perfect score!" << endl;
        }

        else

        {
            cout << "Sorry, you do not have a perfect score." << endl;
        }
    return 0;

}
```

Not sure if I'm on the right track, but I am to pull the score of `100` using:

```
examData.isNumberFound(100);
```

From an array of randomly generated numbers.

Comment: Is [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to search the array `data` for an occurrence of `100`?

Comment: Accessing `data[SIZE]`most likely implies segmentation fault. If an array as a given size `N`, then the element index you can access go from `0` to `N-1`

Answer (score 1):

What are your reasons for using an if-else statement here?
You could just iterate over the elements using a for-loop instead.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++) {
    if(data[i] == someNumber) {
        cout << "Congrats, perfect score!" << endl;
        return true;
    }
}
// Nothing matched..
cout << "Sorry, you do not have a perfect score." << endl;
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem, you have to check if a given number is among a list of randomly generated numbers.

I don't know what you expect exactly from:

```
if (data[SIZE] == someNumber)
```

What this statement does is checking only one element of the array, the one located at index `SIZE`. There is also an additional problem: if `SIZE` corresponds to the size of your array, you are reading outside the limit of your array (=Segmentation fault). If an array has size `N`, the valid indexes go from `0` to `N-1`.

Said this, you should modify your code adding a [loop](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#loops) that checks all the elements of your array. Using a [for loop](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#for), this will look like this:

```
bool StatsArray::isNumberFound(int someNumber) {

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (data[i] == someNumber) {
            cout << "Congrats, you have a perfect score!" << endl;
            return true; //You have found your number, exit the function
        }
    }

    ///You have checked the whole array and the value is not there
    cout << "Sorry, you do not have a perfect score." << endl;
    return false;

}
```